# Firebase observer value affect all collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have on the main view controller of the app, a collection view with a UIButton that needs to be changed when ever the user is changing its status.

I'm using Firebase observer value so when the value has changed it will change the button color and image immediately.

The problem is when I changing the value from the second cell and forward, it will change all the cells to.

I've included images for better understanding:

[This is the cells before changing the value of the second one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Prn.png)

[And this is the what happens after I changed only the second cell values on firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHPhv.png)

As you can see its affect the first cell also.
The values of this observer changing from another view controller using transaction block.

I searched for this problem on google and found similar problems but not a single answer has fixed this problem.

Here is the code of the collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "group_card_cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeGroupCollectionViewCell

    cell.prepareForReuse()
    cell.groupName.text = groups[indexPath.row].name
    cell.groupSchedule.text = "\(groups[indexPath.row].day!), Around \(groups[indexPath.row].time!)"

    cell.cardMoreButtonRef.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.cardMoreButtonRef.tag = indexPath.row

        //Changing card attending color and value:
        self.ref.child("Groups").child(groups[indexPath.row].uid!).child("groupFriendsList").child(currentUser!.uid).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? String else {return}

            switch value{
            case "Going":
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "GoingColor")
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.setImage(UIImage(named: "icons8-checkmark_filled"), for: .normal)
            case "Not Going":
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "NotGoingColor")
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.setImage(UIImage(named: "icons8-delete_sign_filled"), for: .normal)
            case "Maybe":
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "MaybeColor")
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.setImage(UIImage(named: "icons8-minus_math_filled"), for: .normal)
            default:
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "MaybeColor")
                cell.groupAttendButtonRef.setImage(UIImage(named: "icons8-minus_math_filled"), for: .normal)
            }
        }
    return cell
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried retrieving `cell` for a specific indexPath in the Firebase event callback?
 You can use -
 `let specificCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section))` 
to get cell based on just indexPath 
or you can get it using reuse identifier -

```
let idpath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row-1, section: indexPath.section)
let specificCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: idpath)
```

Once you'll have the cell, then you can set the `groupAttendButtonRef` of that cell accordingly.